# How to use StreamWriter to create and write to a text file

Tags: c#, file

I wanted to ask how to use StreamWriter to create and write to a file for which we choose a name using a command line argument.

Comment: There are examples in the documentation.  Not clear what the issue is.  Please be specific.

Comment: There are multiple references available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference code just change the file name with your command line argument.

```
StreamWriter logFile;
        if (!File.Exists("logfile.txt"))
        {
            logFile = new StreamWriter("logfile.txt");
        }
        else
        {
            logFile = File.AppendText("logfile.txt");
        }
        logFile.WriteLine(LogMsg + " : " + DateTime.Now);
        logFile.WriteLine();
        logFile.Close();
```

Comment: And where does it create the file?

Comment: @Sofia190 it will create file in current project directory bin folder

Comment: Is it true if the argument which is the filename is passed to the command line?

Comment: I found it, thank you!